# How To Calculate Columns Selectively in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, calculated-columns

I am creating a Travel Expense Report using Microsoft Access 2007. I am new in creating this. I already created tables and forms in MS Access. I have a meal, transportation, and other allowances in my table. The user of the application will enter his/her expenses for the whole week in the table. I already figured out on how to get the total of each expenses in rows. My problem is how could I get the total of each allowances like the total of all meal, total of all transportation, and total of all other expenses for the entire week..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the design view of your report add report header and footer sections if you don't already have them (this is on the arrange toolbar).

In the report footer add text boxes (report design toolbar) for each expenses total you wish to calculate.  Resize and align the text boxes so they line up with your expenses columns in the detail section.

Change the control source of each expenses total by typing directly into the text box

```
=sum([expensenamehere])
```

e.g.

```
=sum([Meal])
```

you'll need to change the format of each expenses total to Currency (text box properties).